# How to create a mongoose schema that allows to insert unique values for specific dates

Tags: mongoose

I have following mongoose schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5971b0a0d5602b15a8068ab7"),
    "trainnum" : "011Ф",
    "startplace" : "Tashkent",
    "destination" : "Samarkand",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-21T07:43:28.620Z"),
    "weeks" : [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "0"
    ],
    "vagons" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5971daead5602b15a8068abd"),
                    "numvag" : "01K",
                    "seatcount" : "40",
                    "reserves" : [
                            {
                                    "numseats" : "1-10",
                                    "numreserve" : "1",
                                    "_id" : ObjectId("5971daead5602b15a8068abf")
                            },
                            {
                                    "numseats" : "11-27",
                                    "numreserve" : "2",
                                    "_id" : ObjectId("5971daead5602b15a8068abe")
                            }
                    ],
                    "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-21T00:00:00Z"),
                    "date1" : ISODate("2017-07-21T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ],
    "date2" : ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
    "date1" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And I'd like to make numvag unique for particular date. I mean it will not allow me to add same numvag values for existing date1 and date2.

Answer (score 0):

Install `mongoose-unique-validator` via `npm install mongoose-unique-validator` 
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator)

To your normal schema,

```
const myScheme = Mongoose.Schema({
  email : { required: true }
})
```

require the module and append "uniqueValidator" to the end as follows,

```
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const myScheme = Mongoose.Schema({
  email : { required: true }
}).plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

This will now allow you to add another schema other than the default ones,

```
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const myScheme = Mongoose.Schema({
  email : { 
    required: true,
    unique: true
}
}).plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

Therefore, if you try to insert the same record for email, an error is thrown.